# get current options in a fancybox after having selected them

Tags: jquery, select, selected

I have created a fancybox dialog which contains a multiple select (#select-a). Now I have another multiple select within a form outside the fancybox dialog, that has the same options (#select-b).
I want to sync the selected options from #select-a with #select-b and therefore I'm trying to find out which are the options the user has selected within #select-a, but if I try to get them they all return 'false', but I **can** get their values.

Initially, all of the options of #select-a are deselected, so I'm thinking the selections cannot be retrieved. Can it be because the #select-a is in a fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

If you have items using the same ID (e.g. #select-a) than only one of them will be submitted. You can use "onCleanup" callback to access content of fancybox and update your form.

Comment: I have only one select with that ID which is in a div inside the form. This div is loaded into the fancybox dialog. However I don't know what fancybox does with it - does it 'cut' the div from the form into the fancybox content div?
Besides it isn't possible for me to use the onCleanup callback as I am not closing the fancybox dialog yet, after getting the selected options.

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently if I preselect some options within the select-box in the fancybox (they already are selected="selected" when loaded), those options will be passed on POST. If you manually select some more options, they appear to be ignored in the POST... How can this be?..